# is it possible to load images from the directory on web server?

Tags: android, image, http, directory, universal-image-loader

I am currently using nostra image loader for loading images...
in my code i am using like this..

```
 public static final String[] IMAGES = {"http://mywebsite.com/tittle/image1.jpg",
        "http://mywebsite.com/tittle/image2.jpg",
        "http://mywebsite.com/tiitle/image3.jpg",
        "http://mywebsite.com/tittle/image4.jpg",
        "http://mywebsite.com/tittle/image5.jpg",....};
```

Is it possible load images from the directory which has images in it..
  like ""http://mywebsite.com/tittle"

Comment: You mean to say that you want to download images from tittle folder of website without giving a specific image name? Am i right or not?

Answer (score 3):

You want to download all images from a single directory right ?

```
File directory= new File("some public directory");
for (File file : directory.listFiles())
{
   if (FileNameUtils.getExtension(file.getName()).equals("jpg"))
   {
      //get file here
   }
}
```

Comment: will try it and let u know

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear. Can you elaborate which directory are you taking about. Is it the SD Card directory (external memory) , Phone directory (internal memory) or a directory on the web server.

Still for the answer, you can load images from all the above 3 mentoined memories.

This the process of downloading any image from the web server and saving it to local memory:

```
public class DownloadImage
{
   public DownloadImage(String url,String file) throws IOException
   {
        File fileName = new File(file);
        URL myImageURL = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)myImageURL.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        OutputStream fOut = null;
        fOut = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
        myBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fOut);
        fOut.flush();
        fOut.close();

   }
}
```

Make a new class named DownloadImage and copy the above code. Then in "url" pass the HTTP Url from where the image has to be downloaded and in "file" pass the local memory address where the image has to be stored.

Comment: do u think sd card directory and phone directory have http link...the question is about web server

Comment: I believe I have already answered it. Yes, it can be loaded from a folder

Comment: I believe that is what you are looking for @DivyaRamakrishnan

Comment: this is not what i am looking for..i want to load bunch of images .i can't write all those image strings url.so i want to load images from the parent directory which image has in it on  webserver?

Comment: If you want to download a folder then you need to study about Apache VFS, this link might be helpful for you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1724589/download-a-directory-over-http-in-java